# Let's merge [microsoft-metro] and [windows-store-apps] into [windows-runtime]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

For full story and background - read on. For the main question - skip to my suggestions at the end.

**Metro Design Language** or **Microsoft Design Language**

The [microsoft-metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-metro) tag is really bad. There was never a thing called "Microsoft Metro" and I've never heard anyone using such term. The correct term was "[Metro Design Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_%28design_language%29)" and so it was originally about the [design language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_language) that evolved from Windows Media Center and especially Zune and was later adopted to Windows Phone 7, Windows 8 and eventually all Microsoft products and for reasons I don't want to speculate about here it was renamed as the "Microsoft Design Language" and so it was not used much if at all at Stack Overflow unless perhaps in cases when people wanted to write programs imitating the design aspects. Before 2012 it was only that - a design language and life was good.

**Metro Style Apps** or **Windows Store Apps**

When Microsoft announced Windows 8 in 2012 - they announced a new part of the shell and kind of apps for Windows that they called "Metro Style Apps". That was a horrible idea #1 since they had no way to enforce the design of the apps people could publish to the store other than by the default design of the controls they made available. Also supposedly because they were sued by the big box retailer Metro AG about the name which coincided with Microsoft stopping all uses of the term and so the confusion has grown even further. For a while people kept asking Microsoft what names to use instead and Modern UI, immersive UI or immersive apps were thrown as names of the new touch-first area of Windows. Also a codename "Jupiter" leaked which was temporarily either the internal name for the full-screen window hosting the new type of apps or maybe the XAML part of the framework (the UI of the apps can be written either in [winrt-xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winrt-xaml), [winjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winjs) or [directx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directx)). Finally Microsoft started to use the name "Windows Store Apps" for the new type of apps and "Microsoft Design Language" for the design language.

**metro** or **microsoft-metro** - the tags

By this time many people already started associating the term **Metro** with this new type of apps though and so the many of them still confused about the names started tagging their questions as [metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metro). The problem though was that the tag was already reserved by the Java web stack technology, so to separate these - a new tag [microsoft-metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-metro) was created and extensive effort to keep retagging questions tagged as [metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metro) to the new ones was started. Later the Java tag was smartly renamed to [java-metro-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-metro-framework). The problem though is - there is no such thing as "Microsoft Metro"!

**Windows Runtime** and **Windows RT**

The name of the entirely new development framework for creating these "Windows Store Apps" is and always was "Windows Runtime" or "WinRT" for short, but at some point Microsoft had another horrible naming idea and called the version of Windows 8 running on ARM tablets - "Windows RT" - perhaps to maximize confusion.

**Stack Overflow users' take**

With all these terms being used at some points - you now have people using all of them on Stack Overflow, but in virtually all cases these questions are about the same area - building Windows Store Apps, which you actually use Windows Runtime to do. There are following numbers of questions in these categories now:

- [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) (the successor to Windows API) - 4847
- [windows-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps) (the new type of apps) - 3677
- [microsoft-metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-metro) (nominally the design language, but more than 90% of the questions are about the Windows Runtime APIs) - 3890
- [windows-rt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-rt) (the SKU of Windows on ARM devices) - 69
- [modern-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) (the open source WPF project) - 67

**My suggestions**

As a longtime Windows Store Apps developer using Windows Runtime and the Stack Overflow [top answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-runtime/topusers) in the Windows Runtime category - this is my take on the matters. Note that while I currently work for Microsoft building apps for Windows Store - this is only my opinion as a developer and a Stack Overflow user and not the official statement of Microsoft as a whole or any of its product groups', teams' etc.

- [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) This is an undisputed name of the set of technologies for building Windows Store Apps for Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows RT and Windows Phone 8.1. It should be kept as is.
- [windows-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps) Since Stack Overflow is not a discussion about apps and these questions are about building Windows Store Apps which you use WinRT to do - this tag should become a synonym for [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime). There is no distinction whatsoever between the scope of questions categorized with these tags.
- [microsoft-metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-metro) This is a really bad tag. There is no such thing as Microsoft Metro, the tag is said to be about the design language (which shouldn't be within scope of Stack Overflow) and people use it almost exclusively to refer to what was formerly called "Metro Style Apps" and now "Windows Store Apps" and so it should become a synonym to [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) as well - since this is the technology these questions are about.
- [windows-rt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-rt) This is a bit of a tough call. Some of the questions are indeed about specifically problems with WinRT running on ARM devices, but a lot if not most of them are about WinRT in general. While there shouldn't be much work to maintain it as a separate tag and keep retagging these questions as [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) - I think the effort is most likely in vain since there are very few questions actually specific to Windows RT and I doubt anyone is following this tag. I would also make it a synonym to [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) to save the effort.
- [modern-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) I don't think many users still use the name "Modern UI" when thinking about the "Windows Store Apps" and so with few questions and an actual existing library for WPF called "[Modern UI](https://mui.codeplex.com/)" or MUI by [Koen Zwikstra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232458/koen-zwikstra) (the creator of a popular tool called [XAML Spy](http://www.xamlspy.com/)) - I'd keep the tag here and clean it up a bit since many if not most of these questions are actually not about the WPF library, but about writing Windows Store Apps. Since Koen doesn't seem to be monitoring the tag - making it a synonym for [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) is also an option to avoid the need for maintenance, but then it would help to remove the tag from questions actually about the WPF library. Another option might be to rename the tag as something like [modern-ui-wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui-wpf) or [modern-ui-from-codeplex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui-from-codeplex) or some such names, but some people would still probably tag their questions as just [modern-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) and so questions about the library would actually be redirected to [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime), so probably keeping it as is and continuing to maintain it is a better idea. Also retagging some of the [mui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mui) questions as [modern-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) would be good, since MUI is a different, older and established term.

Comment: "Windows Runtime"... Worst name ever.  Completely non-descriptive.  I thought that ".NET Server" was the worst name ever... But I was *wrong,* wasn't I?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if Windows Runtime is worse than Windows API, which really WinRT is a successor to, but anyways - I'm not discussing names - I just feel like unifying the naming under the officially supported one seems like a good idea and for me personally it would make it easier to track and answer all these questions that are really about the same thing. Also - with so many similar terms - 5 tags are often not enough when people ask about the same topic while using tags like windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, C#, xaml and then some more specific tags as well

Comment: Windows Runtime is NOT WindowsRT. Windows Runtime or WinRT is a successor to WinAPI/Win32 - it is the development API for Windows. Windows RT is just a SKU of Windows for ARM devices. I believe there is no such official term as Modern UI. I think it was possibly a term used by someone in transition after Metro meaning the UI framework for building Windows Store apps and while it might be a good thing in lack of a better term - I don't think we should be inventing new names here. Metro apps was what is now called Windows Store apps, while Metro design language is Microsoft design language.

Comment: @FilipSkakun I removed my comment after doing some more research on the subject.  Frankly, Microsoft themselves created the confusion by creating a brand name they decided not to use and not really renaming it into anything.

Comment: I agree, but I don't want to discuss who's to blame. I was not involved in it, so I can't comment on why things are named the way they are, but I would like to remove a misleading and confusing tag and merge it into another one that is basically used for virtually identical set of questions. I probably manually retagged 100-500 questions from microsoft-metro to windows-runtime or windows-store-apps.

Comment: Could you update your question with a *technical* argument on why "Metro" really means "something using Windows Runtime?"  I want to agree, but I'm not convinced.

Comment: @FilipSkakun the point I was trying to make was the problem is a lot bigger than 1 tag.  There are 67 questions tagged [tag:modern-ui], most seem to reference the same ambiguously named technology.  I think this discussion should be more about what the precise name of the technology is and merge and make synonyms of all of the other names to clean up the problem once and for all.

Comment: [Wikipedia suggests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_(design_language)#Name_change) that the current naming is "Microsoft design language," which is corroborated by the various MSDN links you get when Googling about Metro.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Oh, it seems like modern-ui is a tag for some open source library for WPF... An unrelated/very loosely related topic.

Comment: @FilipSkakun not all of the questions seem to be for that library.  That's the entire problem here.  No one really understands the correct names.

Comment: @Charles Yes, that's true, but the problem is the current [tag:Microsoft-Metro] tag is unmaintainable as is. 99% of the questions are actually about apps written using [tag:Windows-Runtime] because these used to be refered to as "Metro Style Apps" and not actually about elements of the Metro design language (currently known as Microsoft Design Language). You can move all these questions to a new "Microsoft Design Language" tag, but then they will be mostly mislabeled. Also I don't think this is a design forum.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Well, I understand these fairly well and can see the confusion among people, that's why I'm bringing up the topic. If we move all these [tag:microsoft-metro] questions into [tag:windows-runtime] - we might help people understand the correct names. As a side note - I want to stress that while I currently work for Microsoft I don't represent the company in what I am saying - I represent the community of developers who currently target Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 as a platform.

Comment: @Charles I've rewritten the question to make it better structured and clearer.

Comment: @FilipSkakun, thank you.  I agree on all points other than merging the tag for the Windows RT operating system.  The questions that should have that tag *usually* have some overlap with the other tags, but not *always*.  It can probably stand on its own.

Comment: +1 for detailed background. However, I cannot comment much on the suggestion since I'm not touching Windows app development at all, even though I have heard some of the terms (especially the so-called "Metro design" at the time Windows 8 was released).

Comment: How about adding a tag named `Windows-Version-RT` and making `Windows-RT` redirect there, just to make wrong tagging immediately obvious to the tagger?

Comment: Never heard of Windows-Version-RT. Sounds like adding confusion to the pot.

Answer (score 15):

The issue here is bigger than 1 tag.  There is a significant amount of ambiguity surrounding the naming of the technology formally known as *metro*.

Your claim is that Windows RT and WinRT (aka Windows Runtime) are completely different, and based on your employment claims in your profile, you would be in a position to know (and some quick googling supports this as well).  However, the names invite significant confusion because not everyone will pay attention to the differences.

There are questions under [windows-rt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-rt) that seem to be about [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime), plus there are a number of questions with the tags [microsoft-metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-metro) and [modern-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui), not to mentioned the [windows-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps) questions, which seems to have a significant overlap.

I completely agree that the tags as they stand now are a problem, but I'm not sure the proposed synonyms are the right way to go.  Tags need to be unambiguous and simple, otherwise you'll ends up with a lot of mistagged questions.

I'm not sure if I have the right solution to this mess, as this seems to be confusion over Microsoft's naming and they kept changing the branding in the years after Windows 8 was released.

---

From the comment chain, I think we have several overlapping issues here.

First is what used to be called "Metro", which was a reference to the gui language.  The proper name of that seems to be [microsoft-design-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-design-language).  That tag current doesn't exist, so probably needs to get created, and any questions about the language should be sent there.

Second, is what used to be "Metro-Style Apps".  That is currently a synonym of [microsoft-metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-metro).  That synonym should be changed to point to [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime).

Thirdly, questions with the [modern-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) tag that actually reference [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) need to be retagged.  The fact that there were brief references to this name when the Metro name was dropped probably have caused some users to think that this name references the metro-style apps.

Last is the confusion between WindowsRT and Windows Runtime.  I'm not sure of the right answer here.  Maybe clean up the current questions that are under the wrong tag, but it may be better to find a better way to limit the confusion in the future.

---

Ultimately, while I agree with the idea that something needs done here, I do not believe that a simple merge is the correct course of action.  You'll be trading the problem of questions with an incorrect tag for a different set of questions with inappropriate tags.  Unfortunately much of the effort is going to be manual labor to get as many of the questions with the wrong tag fixed before we consider synonyms or merging.

From [Charles's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228837/merge-microsoft-metro-into-windows-runtime#comment750637_228847), I see that the Windows-Runtime vs Windows-RT discussion has already taken place in [Sorting out tagging for WinRT (Windows Runtime) and Windows RT (Windows on ARM)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152477/sorting-out-tagging-for-winrt-windows-runtime-and-windows-rt-windows-on-arm) but no clear consensus seems to have been achieved

Comment: I agree with most of what you are saying and it seems like you agree with most of my suggestions. [tag:windows-rt] and [modern-ui] are not a big deal as these can be fairly easily cleaned up manually and I might occasionally do that while also possibly answering some questions. I typically focus on following [tag:windows-runtime] questions since that is the correct and also biggest bucket of where these related questions go, while some might also be specialized with [tag:winjs] or [tag:winrt-xaml] tags.

Comment: @FilipSkakun after a lot of reading, I *finally* understand what Microsoft is calling these things now.   But cleaning it up won't be simple.

Comment: I sometimes also reach into [tag:microsoft-metro] and [tag:windows-store-apps] since these are about the same thing. There are some [tag:microsoft-metro] that are genuinely about design and it might be worth retagging those as [tag:microsoft-design-language] and while StackOverflow is not a design forum - the [tag:microsoft-design-language] is very closely related to programming since programmers often make UI design decisions, but we can't automatically make [tag:microsoft-metro] a synonym for [tag:microsoft-design-language] because people will keep asking WinRT questions tagged as metro...

Comment: @psubsee2003 I've rewritten the question to make it better structured and clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my perspective, and by no means do I think I have the definitive answers on this subject. I should note that my top tags include [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime), [windows-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps), and [windows-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8).

- [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) I agree that this tag should be left the way it is.
- [windows-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps) I lean towards not synonymizing this with [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime). In my view, synonmizing the two would be somewhat akin to synonomizing [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) with [winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms).

  .Net initially shipped with Win Forms, but later came WPF and Silverlight. I am speculating that there will be something else after Windows Store Apps that runs on Windows Runtime.
- [microsoft-metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-metro) I lean towards not synonymizing this with [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime). My reasoning above about [windows-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps) is the same here.

  I do think though that [microsoft-metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-metro) can safely be synonomized with [windows-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps).
- [windows-rt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-rt) I am on the fence on this, but lean towards keeping this as a separate tag to refer to Windows 8.x on Arm. I do think it is important to help distinguish between issues that happen only on the RT (Arm) version, and not the desktop (x86/ x64) version of Windows.
- [modern-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) I don't have much experience with this tag, so I'll not leave an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

(Not a real answer, but a bit long for a comment)

This group of tags is a complete mess.

Rename windows-rt to window-arm then it is clear that the tag has nothing to do with WinRT.

I only care about .net, so I don’t wish to have java script questions mixed up in the .net “metro” related tags.

I don’t like microsoft-design-language as a tag, it sound too much like Microsoft’s version of UML.

Comment: I don't think renaming windows-rt to windows-arm will help. There is no such thing as a Windows ARM (maybe a window's hinge?), so people will keep using windows-rt, unless you'd make these a synonym, but then people will still occasionally use windows-rt when they mean windows-runtime, only their questions will then clearly move to the wrong category.

Comment: As to the .net vs. js question - there is a [tag:winrt-xaml] tag that is specifically for .net store apps, but people often don't use that. Some actually think of it as WPF and use that tag which often leads to confused answers, but is fairly easy to fix and also often the winrt-xaml questions can easily be answered by WPF developers since the technologies are quite similar. Most typically I see .net winrt questions tagged as both [tag:winrt] and [tag:c#].

JavaScript questions are typically tagged with [tag:winjs]. WWA is another term that has been thrown to indicate these.

Comment: I can't comment on your subjective opinion of [tag:microsoft-design-language] as a name, but this is the official name and it is very descriptive, precise and not a marketing jargon. I probably shouldn't be using the term [tag:metro-design-language] as a Microsoft employee although no one ever told me not to but sure - that might be more recognizable than the other term and I like the sound of it. Since it has been officially retired though - I wouldn't use a tag like that anyway other than a synonym for the current name. This is not a design forum though, so I don't really care.

Comment: @FilipSkakun, Over the years Microsoft has provided a lot of design languages it seems each set of developer have a different design language including UML, entry relationship, etc.

Comment: Design language has nothing to do with development. It is more about graphic design, brand identity etc. Think about it more as the shapes, colors and shading of the buttons, icons and logos in Windows and applications.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft themselves originated this confusion because of the confusing names surrounding the new APIs and programming environment.
(Not trying to bash MS here, as I do enjoy using their products, and have a few scars from programming Metro/Runtime/whatever it's called today.  But it was a bit confusing.)

My suggestion is to keep the Metro tag(s) separate, because most of the questions on it/them are probably old and not relevant to modern Windows 10 App Store programming anyway.  IIRC, I have at least one question tagged Metro that is probably only relevant to Windows 8.  The ecosystem has changed so much, that I think there is value in keeping at least the Metro name separate.

Answer (score 1):

A big concern (judging by the number of votes) is that [windows-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) is a completely nondescriptive name, so would be a poor choice for a major tag, all the more an umbrella one.

Maybe if it's renamed to something more descriptive, ppl will be more eager to agree to it?

What about [windows-runtime-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime-api) ? Since "runtime" (an implementation) and API (a specification) are normally mutually exclusive terms, this phrase hints that "runtime" is not just any runtime but a proper name here.

Alternatively, [winrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winrt) [*is* another proper name for the API family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime) -- and will coexist nicely with the existing [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi).